# Apple rejected binary due to not support iPV6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipv6

We have updated reachability class as updated by apple.
We have tested application with create hotspot as suggested by apple [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) and it run perfect.

Please help me out to solve iPV6 related issues.
Apple tester does not able to test app due to they can not able to login and issues is iPV6.

Comment: Thanks Anbu.Karthik, for reply,  we have call GET of  API on that call app didn't crash, but when apple tester try to CALL POST API for login they got crash issues. Please help me to find out solution.

Comment: what you use for api calling

Comment: A wrapper of AFNetworking.